# Most efficient way to select and process data from a dataframe

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe

I would like to load and process data from a dataframe in Spark using Scala.
The raw SQL Statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(
  key_attribute,
  attribute_1,
  attribute_2
)
SELECT
  MIN(TABLE_2.key_attribute),
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as attribute_1,
  'Some_String' as attribute_2
FROM TABLE_2
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_1 
  ON TABLE_2.key_attribute = TABLE_1.key_attribute
WHERE
  TABLE_1.key_attribute IS NULL
  AND TABLE_2.key_attribute IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  attribute_1,
  attribute_2,
  TABLE_2.key_attribute
```

What I've done so far:
I created a DataFrame from the Select Statement and joined it with the TABLE_2 DataFrame.

```
val table_1 = spark.sql("Select key_attribute, current_timestamp() as attribute_1, 'Some_String' as attribute_2").toDF();
table_2.join(table_1, Seq("key_attribute"), "left_outer");
```

Not really much progress because I face to many difficulties:

1. How do I handle the SELECT with processing data efficiently? Keep everything in seperate DataFrames?
2. How do I insert the WHERE/GROUP BY clause with attributes from several sources?
3. Is there any other/better way except Spark SQL?

Comment: Spark SQL, especially with Spark 2, is pretty good at performing optimizations and performing expensive operations in an efficient manner. Have you tried just registering your data sources as tables and running the original query on top of Spark SQL without modifications?

Comment: Converting the Spark DataFrame into an Hive Table and then querying the table with spark sql?

Answer (score 0):

Few steps in handling are -

1. First create the dataframe with your raw data
2. Then save it as temp table.
3. You can use filter() or "where condition in sparksql" and get the
   resultant dataframe
4. Then as you used - you can make use of jons with datframes. You can
   think of dafaframes as a representation of table.

Regarding efficiency, since the processing will be done in parallel, its being taken care. If you want anything more regarding efficiency, please mention it.